# Spread of a rumor in a growing population

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

This is a variation on a [classic problem](http://www.siam.org/students/siuro/vol6/S01182.pdf). It occur's in several problems I am researching and I'd like to get some help from folks who may have dealt with this already or can offer insights.

---

Let $N(t)$ be the size of the population at time $t$. Suppose we start with $N(0)=1$ person. This person has a rumor they want to spread. Now, **the population grows by $a \in \mathbb{N}$ each time step**.

At each time step, let $R(t)$ be the number of people in the population who have been told the rumor up to time $t$. Assume that each person told the rumor also wants to tell it to others (they're a gossipy bunch ;-).

Here are the dynamics:

At time step $t$, each of the $R(t)$ rumor "spreaders" randomly  picks (i.e., discrete uniform distribution) someone in the population (including themselves) to tell the rumor to. Let $T(t)$ be how many of the $N(t)-R(t)$ "ignorants" are told as we go from $t\to t+1$. This means that $R(t+1)=R(t)+T(t)$.

---

### Question

I would like to know for what values of $N(0),R(0)$ and $a$ do the following hold:

$$\ \frac{R(t)}{N(t)} \xrightarrow{w.p.1} L \in [0,1] $$

or,

$$\ \frac{R(t)}{N(t)} \xrightarrow{p} L \in [0,1] $$

and when it exists can we estimate (or exactly calculate) the value of the limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of $N(0), R(0), a$ do not matter, $\frac {R(t)}{N(t)} \to 1$ with probability $1$.  Intuitively, when few people know the rumor, the number who know it doubles every time step.  This will overtake the linear growth rate of the population.  When most of the population knows the rumor, everybody around hears it pretty quickly and the only ones who haven't are people who have only been around a step or two.  These become a small proportion of the population.

Comment: (+1) The intuitive explanation makes sense when $R(t)/N(t)\ll 1$, but I think I need to see a more technical development to understand if the rate at which the rumor propagates approaches  linear rate only at $R(t)=N(t)$ or if it happens earlier. For example if 1000 of 1100 people know a rumor at a given step, what is the expected increase in the number of people who will know the rumor in the next step (counting the arrival of $a$ "ignorants"?)

Comment: If the $a$ newbies arrive before those that know the rumor choose their target, each person who doesn't know has $\frac {1000}{1100+a}$ chance of hearing this time.  If $a=10$, this means there are $110$ who don't know before this stage (including the newbies) and about $10$ after.  Next time there will be only $20$ who haven't heard, only a couple will not hear, and we are essentially at steady state where everybody hears in a cycle or two.

Comment: Ok, I see...not sure why I made this such a big deal in my head. I